# Character limit in Splunk

Tags: splunk, fluent-bit

Just like to ask whether is there any character limit when fluentbit send logs to splunk? How can I increase the character limit via the Splunk Web UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new file called props.conf in "C:\Program Files\Splunk\etc\system\local"

For truncate setting in the props.conf local

```
[host::small_events]
TRUNCATE = 256
```

For more info:

https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.0.5/Admin/Propsconf

[https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/9.0.2/Admin/Wheretofindtheconfigurationfiles#:~:text=Splunk%20software%20uses%20configuration%20files,the%20system%20as%20a%20whole](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/9.0.2/Admin/Wheretofindtheconfigurationfiles#:%7E:text=Splunk%20software%20uses%20configuration%20files,the%20system%20as%20a%20whole).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how the data is sent to Splunk.  If it comes in via HEC then the limit is 1 million bytes (not characters) and cannot be changed.  If the data comes in via port 9997 then it does not have the same limit, but will be truncated at 10,000 bytes.  The truncation can be set for the sourcetype via the `TRUNCATE` attribute in props.conf or at Settings->Source types.

Comment: Thank you for sharing. I actually tried to configure splunk with HEC and used fluentbit to capture logs in kubernetes pods. but I realized the trace message couldn't load completely into the splunk, it is truncated.

Comment: I tried to edit the C:\Program Files\Splunk\etc\system\default\props.config TRUNCATE field to increase the value under the [default], but, it still didn't work..

Comment: NEVER change a setting in a default config file.  Changes only should be made to config files in `local` directories.  See the note at the top of C:\Program Files\Splunk\etc\system\default\props.config.  How large are the events you're trying to index?  What did you set `TRUNCATE` to?

Comment: I used notepad++ to count the text, it is around 13k. I have increased to around 25k, and it is still truncated.

Comment: 13k is a number easily handled both by HEC and traditional onboarding.  It would seem there's an error in the configuration somewhere.  Verify the props.conf settings are correct, are installed on the first heavy forwarder or indexer that sees the data, and that the sourcetype in the input settings matches that in props.